# postgres : relation there even after dropping the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I dropped my database that I had previously created for django using :
`dropdb <database>`

but when I go to the psql  prompt and say `\d`, I still see the relations there :

How do I remove everything from postgres so that I can do everything from scratch ?

Comment: Are you connecting to a different database than you think? `psql -l` will show you all the ones you have—if you see more than you expect, this could be the problem.

Comment: nope. I am not, just checked. All I want now is to reset the postgres to the point I installed it

Comment: You didn't drop the database then.

Comment: I did, and then I created again, but doesn't dropping the database once mean that I am also dropping the tables ?

Comment: How you can be so sure that you really dropped it? What if `dropdb` failed because of lack of permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely somewhere along the line, you created your objects in the template1 database (or in older versions the postgres database) and every time you create a new db i thas all those objects in it.  You can either drop the template1 / postgres database and recreate it or connect to it and drop all those objects by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you never created the tables in the correct schema in the first place.  Either that or your `dropdb` failed to complete.

Try to drop the database again and see what it says.  If that appears to work then go in to postgres and type `\l`, putting the output here.